# How Do You Subtotal with Autofilter in Excel?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, autofilter

I am currently working on an Excel sheet of list of people working in a company.
The company has multiple teams and multiple positions and I've listed them all in an Excel sheet (I am using Excel 2007). And because the positions and the list of people may differ on daily basis (based on who gets promoted or fired) I had to make date column and place a filter on the "date", "position", and "team".

Now I want to make it so that I filter it out for, let's say, year = 2011, position = team manager, team = information tech. team.
I have managed to get this far on my own but now I am wondering when I filter this out (out of 700+ lines), based on the position or team name, if I can add the total number of people under the same team or same positions.

For example, if there are 10 people under information tech. team, can I make it so it displays "total number of people = 10", without me having to count each one of them by hand when I apply the filter?
Also, if there are 4 people under information tech. team as the manager, it would show that "total number of managers under IT team = 4".

Are there any commands or methods I can use in Excel to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the following in the cell you want it in, and it will change, as per [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244789):

```
=SUBTOTAL(3, C2:C1000)
```

Comment: is there a way I can make a column to show the subtotal each time I apply different filters?

Comment: You have thousands of columns, just choose one, not sure what you want.

Comment: Hi Tyler do you mean how do you show it for the entire column?  If so you can replace the C2:C1000 in Lance's example with the address of the column $C:$C and it will subtotal the entire column irrespective of the number of rows, whilst taking account of the AutoFilter.  HTH Dave.